# Passar resultado MySQL para Highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

Tenho o seguinte array, e preciso converte-lo para o Highcharts interpretar e gerar o gráfico, como posso iterar meu array, já que ele retorna a região duplicada mas com valor da venda diferente?

Onde o eixo X seria [nomcin], o name seria [nomreg] e data seria um array com [valven], segue formato do Highcharts, e array retornado pelo PHP:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Outros', 'Peças', 'Tratores'],
    crosshair: true
}


series: [{
    name: 'PR',
    data: [
        49.9, 71.5, 500
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'SC',
    data: [
        83.6, 78.8, 63
    ]

}]



Array (
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [anomes] => 201601
        [codreg] => 41
        [nomreg] => PR
        [codcin] => 1
        [nomcin] => OUTROS
        [valven] => 6835.7000
        [qtdven] => 1078.8000
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [anomes] => 201601
        [codreg] => 42
        [nomreg] => SC
        [codcin] => 1
        [nomcin] => OUTROS
        [valven] => 3129.0000
        [qtdven] => 366.6200
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [anomes] => 201601
        [codreg] => 42
        [nomreg] => SC
        [codcin] => 2
        [nomcin] => PECAS
        [valven] => 346.9100
        [qtdven] => 73.6600
    )

)
```

Resultado SQL:

```
anomes  codreg  nomreg  codcin  nomcin     valven     qtdven  
------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  -----------
201601      41  PR           1  OUTROS  6835.7000    1078.8000
201601      42  SC           1  OUTROS  3129.0000     366.6200
201601      42  SC           2  PECAS    346.9100      73.6600
```

Atualmente fica dessa forma:
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E gostaria que meu gráfico ficasse dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O gráfico irá mostrar vendas por Região, e classificação de um determinado ano.

Comment: Olá @wribeiro , desculpe deixa eu ver se entendi bem, sua dificuldade está em relação a duplicidade da região, como por exemplo o SC que aparece duas vezes isso? Caso sim, vc pode fazer um GROUP BY na sql para resolver...

Comment: @Neo vou editar a pergunta, com alguns prints pra melhor entendimento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oi @wribeiro , Pelo que vi como gostaria no print, vamos ver se montamos adequadamente:

- Vc precisa obter no while os dados assim:

  php:

  ```
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

     $nomreg = $row['nomreg'];
     $valven = $row['valven'];

     $nomreg_chart []= $nomreg;
     $valven_chart_pecs []= $valven; 
     $valven_chart_outros []= $valven;

  }

  //$nomreg_chart_join = join($nomreg_chart,",");
    $nomreg_chart_join = "'".implode("','",$nomreg_chart)."'";
    $valven_chart_pecs_join = join($valven_chart,",");
    $valven_chart_outros_join = join($valven_chart,",");  


  aplicando no highchart:

   xAxis: {
          categories: [<?php echo $nomreg_chart_join; ?>],
          crosshair: true
      },
  ```

  series: [{
      name: 'Peças',
      data: [
          
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'Outros',
      data: [
          
      ]

  }]
- Crie duas sqls, onde uma estará filtrando com where "outros", e where "peças".

Comment: só que dessa forma ele irá repetir o SC certo? com join retornaria 'PR, SC, SC' ?

Comment: Estou usando code igniter, e pego o resultado dessa forma, 
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM dadf513 WHERE anomes ='$anomes';";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);

            return $query->result();

e no final me retorna aquele array que está logo acima

Comment: vou fazer uma correção na resposta para que o formato seja apresentado no categories corretamente... e para que o SC(região) não repita vc pode usar um GROUP BY na sql

Comment: Eu uso uma outra rotina com trigger, mas acho que nao preciso citar aqui, mas nela eu faço o agrupamento GROUP BY 
codcin, codreg, e faço inserção na tabela onde fica os dados prontos, por isso ali so uso select *, nesse caso ele precisa agrupar pelo codigo da classificacao e pela regiao

Comment: Se vc está fazendo um group by no codreg, então não deverá repetir na query. E para que seja inserido corretamente no formato highcharts seria interessante montar algo assim como mostrei na resposta: $nomreg_chart_join = "'".implode("','",$nomreg_chart)."'";

Comment: Certo eixo X ok

Comment: certo, vou editar a resposta para colocar o data com 'valven'.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81585/discussion-between-neo-and-wribeiro).